# Como remover \n ao ler linhas de um arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um gráfico usando um arquivo CSV por meio do `matplotlib`, porém quando printo percebo que ele fica com `\n` no final de cada linha, a questão é como posso resolver?

Meu código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(a):
    lista = []
    for i in a:
        lista.append(i)
    return lista

lst = open(("wealth-per-country.csv"), "r").readlines()
with open("wealth-per-country.csv", "r") as lst:
    print(func(lst.readlines()))
```

Como ele printa:

```
['Country,Median_Wealth,Mean_Wealth,Population\n', 'Switzerland,"227,891","564,653","6,866"\n', 'Australia,"181,361","386,058","18,655"\n', 'Iceland,"165,961","380,868",250\n', 'Hong Kong,"146,887","489,258","6,267"\n', 'Luxembourg,"139,789","358,003",461\n', 'Belgium,"117,093","246,135","8,913"\n', 'New Zealand,"116,433","304,124","3,525"\n', 'Japan,"110,408","238,104","104,963"\n', 'Canada,"107,004","294,255","29,136"\n', 'Ireland,"104,842","272,310","3,491"\n', '\n']
```

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330535) tem várias opções. Quanto ao seu código, bastaria fazer `with open('arquivo') as arq: lista = [ line.rstrip('\n') for line in arq ]` que vc já terá a lista (não tem porque abrir o arquivo várias vezes). E a sua função `func` não faz sentido, pois recebe uma lista e adiciona todos os elementos em outra lista, sem mudar nada (vc poderia imprimir direto o retorno de `readlines`, pois ele já retorna a lista)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duas formas: (Existem várias)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(a: str):
    lista = []
    for i in a:
        lista.append(i.replace('\n', ''))
    return lista

lst = open(("wealth-per-country.csv"), "r").readlines()
with open("wealth-per-country.csv", "r") as lst:
    print(func(lst.readlines()))
    
# OU

def func(a):
    lista = []
    for i in a:
        lista.append(i)
    return [barraN.replace('\n', '') for barraN in lista]

lst = open(("wealth-per-country.csv"), "r").readlines()
with open("wealth-per-country.csv", "r") as lst:
    print(func(lst.readlines()))
```